# User-data Powershell script is not populating variable

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I have written a Powershell script to initialize, format, assign drive letter etc to a number of EBS volumes attached to a Windows 2019 EC2 instance.

```
<powershell>

New-Item C:\windows_initialization.log -type file -force
    $log = "C:\windows_initialization.log"


Add-Content $log "Downloading aws cli"
Write-Output "Installing AWS Command Line Interface tools"
msiexec.exe /i "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi"
Start-Sleep -s 60
$env:Path +=";C:\Program Files\Amazon\awscliv2"


$profile_drive = aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.device,Values="xvdf" Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id" -usebasicparsing) --output text --query 'Volumes[*].[VolumeId]'
Start-Sleep -s 5
Get-Disk | where SerialNumber -match "$profile_drive".Trim("vol-") | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter D -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -Filesystem NTFS -Confirm:$false
Set-Volume -DriveLetter D -NewFileSystemLabel "Profiles"

$data_drive = aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.device,Values="xvdg" Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id" -usebasicparsing) --output text --query 'Volumes[*].[VolumeId]'
Start-Sleep -s 5
Get-Disk | where SerialNumber -match "$data_drive".Trim("vol-") | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | New-Partition -DriveLetter E -UseMaximumSize | Format-Volume -Filesystem NTFS -Confirm:$false
Set-Volume -DriveLetter E -NewFileSystemLabel "Data"

</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

I thought it was working fine until I connected to my Instance using SSM. The drive initialization didn't work as the variable wasn't populated. I've obviously missed something but I cannot for the life of me think what it is at the moment and need help.

When connected to the instance I can run the `$profile_drive` command manually and it creates a variable and populates it with the required volume_id.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you run the script through PowerShell ISE what did you find?  Which variable exactly isn't being set?

Comment: From my example above it is the $profile_drive and data_drive variables.

Comment: So what is the value of data_drive, or is it uninitialized? You can use PowerShell ISE to initiate a breakpoint on the line.  If it's uninitialized it means that describe-volumes isn't returning what you think it's returning.

Comment: The value contained within the variable is the EBS volume_id. As I said the AWS cli command when executed manually grabs the volume id and creates the variable. I can then execute the Get-Disk manually and it again works as expected.

Comment: The error log shows:

```PS C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\InvokeUserData> cat .\InvokeUserdataErrors.log
Get-Disk : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
At
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\InvokeUserData\UserScript.ps1:26
char:1
+ Get-Disk | where SerialNumber -match "$env:profile_drive".Trim("vol-" ...

```

Comment: ^^^ The above error to me is written because the variable isn't created so the Get-Disk and Set-Volume commands fail.

Comment: You should [edit] your question instead of providing unformatted error messages in 
 a comment.  The point of running the script through PowerShell ISE was to either determine what the value was or catch the error exception that was being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I actually took a fresh look at this and used the Powershell command
`New-Variable -Name profile_drive -Value (aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.device,Values="xvdf" Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id" -usebasicparsing) --output text --query 'Volumes[*].[VolumeId]')`